# Windows8 Metro Applications, change PackageUserInformation from Staged to Installed?

Tags: windows-8, powershell, modern-ui

Curious problem I'm running into. We have a series of Samsung ATIV Smart PC 700T's that come pre-installed with Windows 8 core. Unfortunately we need these on the domain so we're upgrading them to Windows 8 Enterprise/Pro. In doing so, a curious problem's come up.

The package that Samsung provided on the core Windows 8 had several Metro UI applications. S Note, S Camera, S Gallery, so forth... Once we upgraded these machines to Pro, these applications still exist.... but only on one account. They are not available to any domain account that logs into the system. I've tried contacting Samsung to see if it were possible to obtain the individual .appx files to install manually through powershell, but I haven't heard a single word back.

So, in the interest of learning something I started to poke around with powershell. I've found that the applications are flagged as "[Unknown User]: Installed" when I compiled a list using get-appxpackage -allusers. Some of the other Metro UI applications are set to staged.

Now my question is... is there a way through powershell or otherwise to assign these "[Unknown User]: Installed" applications to a user or at least change the PackageUserInformation to make them Staged instead?